# Is using a CA more secure if I'm self-signing anyway?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

We have a web application that we run for clients at their booth on fairs. The communication between clients and the server was done over HTTP until recently.

We're currently working on improving several security-related aspects of this application. For example, I now implemented support for HTTPS and wrote a small script to generate a self-signed certificate for the server. The clients should add this certificate to their trusted certificate stores so that the browser doesn't complain about it. So far so good.

On chat, someone mentioned that I should never use a standalone, self-signed certificate and that I should instead use a certificate authority to sign my certificate, even if the CA itself is self-signed.

Given that I would still have to manually trust the self-signed CA on the clients, I don't see how this would have any benefit from a security standpoint. I guess it would be slightly more *convenient* in certain cases, but we usually erase the clients and server after each deployment and reimage the next time we need to set the system up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The distinction depends on some details about the self-signed certificate and how the browser and the OS will react to it.

**A normal certificate** includes a [`Basic Constraints`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9) extension which contains a flag telling whether the certificate is for a CA or not; when the flag is `TRUE` then the certificate is considered acceptable as an issuer for other certificates. If the extension is altogether missing, then the certificate is to be considered as non-CA.

**Root CA certificates** are "special"; they are not true certificates. They are *trust anchors*; a TA is, nominally, a public key coupled with a name. It is *traditional* to encode trust anchors as certificates, and since a certificate includes a field for a signature, some bytes must be stored there; there again, Tradition says that we shall make the certificate *self-signed*. Nobody really checks that signature, though; junk bytes of approximately the right size would serve just as well.

The tricky point is then that the interpretation of the certificate extensions, if any, found in such a "root CA certificate", is non-standard. In particular, some historical root CA date from before the invention of the `Basic Constraints` extension; as true certificates, they would be interpreted as "not CA", but since they are trust anchors disguised as certificates, the normal interpretation rules do not apply.

So on some browsers or OS, a non-CA certificate (lacking a `Basic Constraints` extension, or even featuring one with the `cA` flag set to `FALSE`), once installed in the "root CA" store, may very well begin to be accepted as a CA. Thus, confidentiality of the private key for any certificate installed in the user's trust store is rather critical.

**What's the difference in your case ?** After all, in your situation, there are two choices:

- You create a self-signed certificate for your server, and the user installs that certificate as "trusted".
- You create a self-signed *CA* certificate, that the user installs as "trusted". You *issue* a normal certificate for your server with this CA.

In both cases, the user surrenders his security to some certificate from you, that the user installs as "trusted". So what would it change ?

The difference is that if you use a custom CA, you can store the corresponding private key with good protection. For instance, you do the CA business on a laptop which is kept offline at all times. There is no possibility of a remote exploit when there is no network at all. Root CA should always be offline, and used only as part of manual procedures and USB keys for data transfer. On the other hand, your server is, well, a server, so it is online and intrinsically exposed. An attacker who hacks into your server may get a copy of the server's private key. If the corresponding public key has been installed as "trusted root" in the users' machines, then the attacker gains a lot of leverage on these machines as well.

Briefly said, making a custom CA distinct from the server's certificate (as used all day long) allows for better protection of the private key, and thus a lower risk of catastrophic attacker's power escalation.

**There are browsers which are not as vulnerable**. What you really want, with a self-signed server certificate, is that the users trust that certificate *only* for SSL connections (not as a CA), and *only* for that specific server. Firefox knows how to do that; it is called a "security exception" in Firefox terminology (see the Preferences -> Advanced -> Certificates -> View Certificates, then the "Servers" tab).

Comment: No mention of certificate revocation?

Comment: In the specific context of this question, it seems that going through all clients and servers on a non-regular basis is "acceptable". Revocation is a way to "cancel" a certificate whose private key has been compromised; it makes coping with such an event easier (no need to go through all clients to change a trusted root) but at some expense (you have to produce the CRL regularly and distribute it, which is at odds with the notion of an "offline CA"), and it is asynchronous (the attacker gets a few hours of days to play).

Comment: As I understand the context, in case of compromise, all server and client systems could be manually inspected anyway. I am here interested in containing potential damage between server compromise and manual intervention; for that, revocation does not seem to add much value.

Comment: But even if you use a CA to issue a certificate, the certificate's private key is still needed at the server so it can use the certificate, so the private key is still subject to being compromised, right?

Comment: The CA private key is needed on the machine which issues certificates; that needs not be the same as the SSL server. In particular, the CA can be an offline machine. What the SSL server needs is the private key _for the SSL server's own certificate_. Having a separate CA allows for easier damage containment in case of compromise of the SSL server (if the CA is offline, it is assumed that it cannot be compromised remotely).

Comment: Yes, but compromise of a single certificate's private key equals compromise of a single server, whether the cert was self-signed itself or issued from a self-signed CA, doesn't  it?